# Development Mode - Swapping to Development environment...error message when I publish to Azure

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-core, publish

I am getting the Development Mode - Swapping to Development environment...error message when I publish to Azure. I can publish to IIS and run the entire Core Web App (forms included) without error but when I publish to Azure only the plain HTML pages in the app work, clicking on any pages with forms / db links returns the Development Mode error. I've adjusted all the ASPNETCORE settings to Development and added a Web.Config file with the same to the project root directory but nothing resolves this problem. It duplicates in Google Cloud too. Any suggestions?